# Do I need to wipe and reinstall after possible hacker attack

Tags: arch-linux, security

Yesterday I noticed that the xterm title I use changed suddenly to something strange.
So I suspect that someone hacked my Linux laptop (I'm using Arch).
I changed the WiFi parameters (pass, essid) and changed my password on the computer.
I also reinstalled all packages to overwrite files that may have been changed.
I tried to take a look at the changed files, logs and so on, but I don't have experience in security, so it was like walking in the dark ;) and of course I didn't found any signs of intrusion.
Do you think I should wipe the system and install from scratch?

Comment: Maybe you should be more precise about "something strange" first, unless you are *positive* there isn't any other possible explanation.  This would be an odd clue for someone to give you if they actually meant harm.

Comment: yes, I agree that's strange, but I think something is wrong when a xterm window changes to something like "Thanks for the ride". it's not a configuration change. maybe it was just a script kiddie who wanted to signal that my wifi is poorly protected? i don't know. I checked the system with rkhunter and unhide and I don't see anythin suspicious.

Comment: As wilf points out, the title of a GUI terminal is easily changed; it could have been a legit application.  So if that's all you have to go on and you've run some checks, don't worry.  And of course **always keep your important stuff backed up *somewhere not attached to the system*.**  Ideally somewhere not attached to any system.  By "important" I don't mean everything.  It is easy to re-install and backing up an entire installation is not worthwhile with a normal workstation.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment - but I can't (currently 20 rep).

Apparently you can change the title by just running a command - but this does not work for me - http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title.html

You can also configure other stuff in xterm- 
http://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2013/07/hidden-gems-of-xterm.html

You can also check who has logged in and when by running the `last` command *(look for tty - that may be the first port of call for anyone logging in remotely)* - unless the 'hacker' (technically its *'cracker'*) modified the log file - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-display-date-and-time-of-login/

For reinstalling, just back up your `/home` and anything else you want to keep, and then to a fresh install which would wipe the previous installtion.

**But** you may not need to do this, as it may be just your system ran an update which changed xterm's configuration - 'crackers' may have better things to do than modify Window title names.